# Dubious Facebook JavaScript API initialization code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

Is this Facebook suggested code somewhat dangerous? It's what they suggest for working with jQuery and the Facebook JavaScript API:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
    $.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_UK/all.js', function(){
    FB.init({
      appId: 'YOUR_APP_ID',
      channelUrl: '//yourapp.com/channel.html',
    });     
    $('#loginbutton,#feedbutton').removeAttr('disabled');
    FB.getLoginStatus(updateStatusCallback);
  });
});
```

The jQuery documentation warns strongly against the use of ajaxSetup(). Enabling caching might well have serious consequences for web pages that make use of asynchronous Ajax calls. For instance if you were periodically calling a PHP file that returned a current exchange rate, you'd probably get the same result for every call.

If the call to ajaxSetup() is a must, and it is important, then perhaps:

```
$.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_UK/all.js', function(){
  FB.init({
    ...
});
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

would be appropriate? Opinions please.

Comment: Facebook wants the SDK to be loaded as fast as possible for a good user experience, and since so many sites on the web use the SDK, chances are quite high that it is already cached. Undermining this by appending the current timestamp to the script source (which is what getScript does by default) would be counter-productive in that regard.

Comment: Setting the option back to false inside the callback handler would still have it be set to true until the request is finished – so other requests that might get fired within that time span would use the setting true also. So I’d rather set it back immediately _after_ the getScript call – that should be enough for that method to not add the timestamp, no need to wait until the script is actually loaded and the callback executed.

Comment: Agreed - better immediately after the getScript call if jQuery just appends a timestamp. Will edit my question.

Comment: Keep in mind that this would affect all of your ajax calls. Why not simply pass the parameter to the specific request?